# How to change UiCollectionView cell size when device orientation changes?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, screen-orientation

I am using UICollectionView and setting the size of the cell using the following method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, 313)
    }
```

Cell size is okay when the view is loaded. But, when orientation changes the cell size is not updated according to view width and height.

I tried to detect the device orientation and did it properly. When device orientation changes, the following method is called:

```
func rotated()
{
    self.shareLogCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**But, I get the following error:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

So, how can I update the cell size and adjust according to the changes of device orientation? Kindly help!

Comment: 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' is shown when an unwrapping object is nil. Please check whether shareLogCollectionView has the right outlet connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right! I have somehow referenced the outlet improperly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @krishnanunni already mentioned,

Please check whether shareLogCollectionView has the right outlet connected.
This is a very common mistake.

also for rotate you can use `viewWillTransitionToSize`

Please check.